# Fade Background Color on Update Panel

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, updatepanel

I have a radajaxpanel that is populated with the selected item from a combobox on another update panel.  Currently the radajaxpanel is the same background color as the rest of the page.  What I'd like to do, is based on it being populated with data, change it's background color to a muted red.

I want it to stand out as an action that has bad consequences.  In other words, you're about to delete or close something.

How would I fade the red background IN after they've made their selection in the combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at doing this with some custom JavaScript.  I can't recommend highly enough looking at the [JQuery](http://jquery.com) library - there's not much you can't do with it in a line or two of code!